# The type or namespace name 'Smartphone' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I tried to pass a list of smartphone data to the Index views, I encountered this problem:

*One or more compilation references may be missing. If you're seeing this in a published application, set 'CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory' to true in your project file to ensure files in the refs directory are published.*

*The type or namespace name 'Smartphone' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

[The error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08jui.png)

I already import the namespace but the error is still there. The file Index.cshtml:

```
@using MyApp.Models
@model List<Smartphone>
```

And also set `CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory` to `true` .
I'm appreciated if you guys can help me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MyApp.Models as namespace for models then, You can try like this

```
@model List<MyApp.Models.Smartphone>
```

Note: Please check your view location as well it should be in proper folder as controller name.